# Oracle: Adding, renaming, and dropping columns on live database

Tags: database, oracle, renaming

What operations are permitted and not permitted on a live, running Oracle database? Specifically, how is this handled when adding, dropping, and renaming columns?

Comment: I would be extremely wary of renaming columns. There is a lot of stuff you could break doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add, drop, and rename columns without issue.

Caveats,

adding a column with a default value forces the database to issue an update statement for existing rows.  Be careful on large tables or the load will spike.

rename a column can break your app.  Plan for this but otherwise you should be fine.  Also realize that you will be generating errors for queries that try to access the column unless you plan things properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can make almost all changes like this on a running instance. Of course I wouldn't recommend doing this with USERS in the system.

That said, Oracle 11.2 has a killer new feature called EBR, Edition-Based-Redefinition. Think of it like being able to "commit" and "rollback" DDL changes. That might be useful, depending upon circumstance.

Comment: If I had the need to do this (especially on a large highly used table), I would definitely schedule the task when users are not on the system or shut down the application for a maintenance window.

Comment: EBR is massively complex and is an extra license option.  I can think of only a few cases when this is practical.

Comment: I understood EBR to be an integral feature of the database, but could be mistaken. And "massively complex" may be unimportant if the feature's use is necessary. It was merely presenting an option.

Answer (score 2):

Online changes (ie while other sessions are active) can be done using [DBMS_REDEFINITION](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_redefi.htm) (described [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/tables.htm#sthref2335), [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/HighAvailabilityEnhancements9i.php#OnlineTableRedefinition) and [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/OnlineTableRedefinitionEnhancements_10gR1.php)) but that is an Enterprise Edition [feature](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/license.102/b14199/editions.htm#BABJICBB)

Comment: That looks very useful.  Do you ever get transaction failing due to package recompilation using that?  That's usually our biggest issue changing the active database.  Ever more odd is 11i session seem to lose their user_id so fnd_global.user_id returns -1.

Answer (score 1):

you can do those things.  if the database finds a reason to disallow the change, you will get a nice nastygram with a cool error code you can check for what you need to do next.

you will have less trouble if there are no other users runnign queries or no jobs running in the background tc.